# How to return from a nested function handler in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, return, nested-function

I've got this code:

```
function fetchSocialCount(type,fileSrc){
    var count = {likes: 0, dislikes: 0};
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onload = function(){
        if(req.status === 200 && req.readyState === 4){
            var countResponse = json_encode(req.responseText);
            count.likes = countResponse.likes;
            count.dislikes = countResponse.dislikes;
            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

So, I want to return `count` from the `req.onload` function expression, as if it was returned from the `fetchSocialCount` function. How can I achieve this?

Comment: *"How can I achieve this?"* You can't. Just like you have to assign a function to `onload` to get the response, the caller of `fetchSocialCount` has to pass a function to `fetchSocialCount` (or something similar). This is one of the most asked JavaScript questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

req.onload is asynchronous. You need to use callbacks, promises, or something similar to get the resulting "count"

```
function fetchSocialCount(type,fileSrc, cb){
    var count = {likes: 0, dislikes: 0};
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onload = function(){
        if(req.status === 200 && req.readyState === 4){
            var countResponse = json_encode(req.responseText);
            count.likes = countResponse.likes;
            count.dislikes = countResponse.dislikes;
            cb(count);
        }
    }
}

//calling fetchSocialCount
fetchSocialCount(my_type, my_file_src, function(count){
    //here it is
    console.log(count);
});
```